# [CFDictionary count]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios4

My app is calling the **rqst_run** method below in **didViewLoad** method but I've an error. Debugger reports the following error:

```
[CFDictionary count]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

and debug marker is placed on this line (in tableView numberOfRowsInSection method below):

```
if([self.listing_items count] > 0)
```

I don't know where this variable get released

Declared in header file (interface section):

```
NSMutableString        *rqst_error;
NSMutableData      *rqst_data;
NSMutableDictionary    *listing_items;
```

and I defined this method in implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if([self.listing_items count] > 0)
    {
        if([self.listing_items objectForKey:@"items"])
        {
            return [[self.listing_items objectForKey:@"items"] count];
        }
    }
}

- (void)rqst_run
{
    rqst_data = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSMutableURLRequest *http_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.feedserver.com/request/"]];
    [http_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *post_data = [[NSString alloc] initwithFormat:@"param1=%@&param2=%@&param3=%@",rqst_param1,rqst_param2,rqst_param3];
    [http_request setHTTPBody:[post_data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    rqst_finished = NO;
    [post_data release];
    NSURLConnection *http_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:http_request];
    [http_request release];

    if(http_connection)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

        if([rqst_data length]>0)
        {
            NSString *rqst_data_str = [[NSString alloc] rqst_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
            SBJsonParser *json_parser = [[SBJsonParse alloc] init];
            id feed = [json_parser objectWithString:rqst_data_str error:nil];
            listing_items = (NSMutableDictionary *)feed;
            [json_parser release];
            [rqst_data_str release];
        }   
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Feed" message:@"No data returned" delegate:self cancemButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
   }
   else
   {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Problem" message:@"Connection to server failed" delegate:self cancemButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
   }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [rqst_data setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [rqst_data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [rqst_data release];
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [rqst_data release];
    [connection release];
    rqst_finished = YES;
}
```

Comment: Where are you allocating `listing_items`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSMutableDictionary must be properly initialized before use. In your code you assign feed to listing_items and then release it. It haven't been retained so listing_items is also removed. 
Try to init dictionary like this:

```
listing_items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:feed];
```

and all should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
listing_items = (NSMutableDictionary *)feed;
```

Use this

```
self.listing_items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:feed];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear that:
 * You use the instance variable instead of the property to assign the value to `listing_items`
 * You put an autoreleased value in this ivar.

`listing_items = (NSMutableDictionary *)feed;` is clearly your error because `feed` is an autorleased variable (and then will be deallocated at the end of the current runloop by definition.

Either declare a `@property(retain)` for `listing_items` and use it each time you want to assign (autoreleased) value to it (so that the property will manage the retain/release on assignation)

Or retain the stored value manually (but this is painful as you need not to forget to release the previous value before assigning a new one to `listing_items` each time... which is what the setter method does when called either directly or thru the property assignment)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to initialize your NSMutableDictionary. Right now its just a pointer pointing to feed. when feed gets released, it just points to nil.

in the viewDidLoad :
listing_items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

or you need to retain the data:
listing_items = [(NSMutableDictionary *)feed retain];

Answer (score 0):

```
SBJsonParser *json_parser = [[SBJsonParse alloc] init];
id feed = [json_parser objectWithString:rqst_data_str error:nil];
listing_items = (NSMutableDictionary *)feed;
[json_parser release];
```

When you release the `json_parser`, the dictionary it holds is released too.
So, as others said, you need to retain the dictionary obtained from `json_parser`.